# grails: setting log threshold at environment level?

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j

So I'm using a Grails log appender in Config.groovy like this:

```
console name: 'stdout',
  threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.FATAL

appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "full",
  threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR,
  file: "/tmp/test.log" );
```

I have environment config like this:

```
environments {
  root {
    info 'full', 'stdout'
    additivity=true
  }
  development {
  }
}
```

How do I change the thresholds when in the development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root {
    additivity=true
}
environments {
    development {
        info 'full', 'stdout'
    } 
    stage {
        info 'full', 'stdout'
    }
    production {
        error 'full', 'stdout'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
environments {
  root {
    info 'full', 'stdout'
    additivity=true
  }
  development {
     appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "test",
       threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,
       file: "/tmp/test.log" );
  }
}
```

Comment: What I'd like to do is change the thresholds on "full" and "stdout", not add appenders in different environments.